# AutoMapper - Map source object to nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

How to map a single object to a nested object?

The below one is my entity.

```cs
class Employee
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string city_name { get; set; }
    public string State_name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map to

```cs
class Employee
{
    public string Name;
    public Location Location;
}

class Location
{
    public string City;

    public string State;
}
```

Please note that the property names are different. Can anyone help to map these using AutoMapper?

Comment: You should just check the [automapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html) and create a custom mapping. looks like the automapper documentation sample is pretty similar to your scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1: `ForPath`

**1.1** Create `Profile` instance with inheriting from `Profile` and put the configuration in the constructor.

**1.1.1** Using [ForPath](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html?highlight=forpath#forpath) to map nested property.

```cs
public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
{
    public EmployeeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Location.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.city_name))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Location.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.State_name));
    }
}
```

**1.2** Adding profile to mapper configuration

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.AddProfile<EmployeeProfile>();

        // Note: Demo program to use this configuration rather with EmployeeProfile
        /*
        cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Location.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.city_name))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Location.State, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.State_name));
        */      
    });
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        
    var employee = new Employee{name = "Mark", city_name = "City A", State_name = "State A"};

    var employeeDto = mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeDto>(employee);
}
```

[Sample Solution 1 on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUgbdm)

---

### Solution 2: `AfterMap`

**2.1** Create `Profile` instance with inheriting from `Profile` and put the configuration in the constructor.

**2.1.1** Using [AfterMap](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html?highlight=aftermap#before-and-after-map-action) to perform mapping nested property after map occurs.

```cs
public class EmployeeProfile : Profile
{
    public EmployeeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => { dest.Location = 
                    new Location {
                        City = src.city_name,
                        State = src.State_name
                    };
                });
    }
}
```

**2.2** Adding profile to mapper configuration

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.AddProfile<EmployeeProfile>();

        // Note: Demo program to use this configuration rather with EmployeeProfile
        /*
        cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => { dest.Location = 
                    new Location {
                        City = src.city_name,
                        State = src.State_name
                    };
                });
        */      
    });
    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        
    var employee = new Employee{name = "Mark", city_name = "City A", State_name = "State A"};

    var employeeDto = mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeDto>(employee);
}
```

[Sample Solution 2 on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lk0tzu)

---

### References

1. [`ForPath`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html?highlight=forpath#forpath)
2. [Profile Instances](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances)
3. [Before and After Map](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html?highlight=aftermap#before-and-after-map-action)